# Fetch API not posting to Node.js server (body is empty)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I'm trying to use fetch() to post to another Node.js server I am running. When I take out the headers, my console prints '{}'. When I keep them in, nothing is printed when I call the function.

I have tried using curl and I receive '{}' as well.

```
//Server.js (what I am trying to POST to)
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 4000;
app.use(express.json());


app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);

})
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('server running on port: ' + PORT);
})

//Post function (this is inside a separate React component which will perform the POST)
postContents() {
    var data = { username: 'example' };

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)));
  }
```

Comment: is this a cross origin request? your URL includes hostname and port so I assume it is ... does your server handle OPTIONS request? any error in the browser console regarding CORS? Is the only request made an OPTIONS request?

Comment: the fact that removing the headers changes the result strongly suggests a CORS issue

Comment: @JaromandaX that was the problem! I used this: http://johnzhang.io/options-request-in-express

Comment: @rightsidepillow Which is your `express` version?

Comment: In the server side code you show, there's nothing there that actually reads the body (usually body-parser middleware).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the body-parser as a middleware for your express server.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem, unfortunately. I have tried this, but it is pretty much the same as just using `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: @rightsidepillow - Do you understand that `req.body` is not automatically available on a `POST` request.  Some piece of code HAS to read the incoming stream in order to create the `req.body` property and fill it with data.  That's what `body-parser` does if you use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

- without headers and with headers the result is different
- the URL is fully qualified with host and port

These two points suggest you are making a cross origin request.

The solution is to have the server

- accept and handle OPTIONS requests when required
- issue CORS headers in the response